# Apache redirect simple url to the same named php file

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'd like to redirect some static pages to the same named php file.
This is the code I'm using:

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      RewriteEngine On
      RewriteBase /

      RewriteRule ^services$ services.php [L,QSA]
    </IfModule>
```

I'm getting 404 error when I open the "/services" url. If I change it to

```
      RewriteRule ^services-anything$ services.php [L,QSA]
```

I can open "/service-anyting" without any problem.

Does anybody have any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of your rewrite rules you can just enable `MultiViews` option:

```
Options +MultiViews
```

- Option `MultiViews` is used by `Apache's content negotiation module` that runs before `mod_rewrite` and and makes Apache server match extensions of files. So `/file` can be in URL but it will serve `/file.php`.